# Jquery Selector library for iOS

Tags: jquery, ios, objective-c

for my project I am trying to find a library can run jquery selector queries on a html code(html as in string).
Normally I am creating a zerorect uiwebview putting html inside of it, add jquery and then run the selector for results but it is too much time consuming.
I found some html parsing libraries but none of them work for this kind of jquery selector

***img:not([src^='javascript:'])***

are there better (faster) way to do it?

Comment: For something as specific as that, you could probably make a string search that would work rather than parsing into a whole DOM.  I guess it depends upon what you're trying to actually do once you've found a matching image tag.

Comment: Try this libraries WebViewJavascriptBridge

https://www.google.lk/search?q=WebViewJavascriptBridge&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&rls=org.mozilla:en-US:official&client=firefox-a&channel=sb&gws_rd=cr&ei=759YVJKvE8bZ8gXK7ICoBw